# dd failed with 'illegal numeric value'

Tags: sd-card, ubuntu

I am following the instructions here https://developer.ubuntu.com/core/get-started/installation-medias to prepare an OS image on the sd card.

I ran the following command:

```
xzcat ~/raspberry-pi/ubuntu-core-16-pi3.img.xz | sudo dd of=/dev/disk2 bs=32M
```

But it failed with the following message:

```
dd: bs: illegal numeric value
```

If I removed the `bs` parameter altogether, I got

```
dd: /dev/disk2: Resource busy
```

I am using OSX 10.13.4

Here is the output from `distutil`

```
$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         500.0 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +500.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            432.1 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 44.4 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                1.0 GB     disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      11.8 GB    disk1s4

/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *16.0 GB    disk2
   1:             Windows_FAT_32 NO NAME                 16.0 GB    disk2s1
```

It is what I see in Finder

[image]

Comment: see https://superuser.com/q/909391/865454

Comment: You need to `diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk2` before doing `dd`. The `illegal numeric value` error happens because the `dd` on macOS expects lowercase letters, so change `bs=32M` to `bs=32m` (lowercase `m`).

Comment: See my answer on [How can I create a bootable USB stick on an Apple Macbook](https://askubuntu.com/questions/801458/how-can-i-create-a-bootable-usb-stick-on-an-apple-macbook/1017560#1017560)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is almost certainly because you failed to unmount `/dev/disk2`
The following is the script I use (but does not specifically handle `xz`).

PS Failure to use raw disk mode can result in glacially slow writes on `macOS`.

> NOTE These days I just use `Etcher` which is easier (and safer)

```
#!/bin/bash
# script to restore backup to Pi SD card
# 2017-08-26

DSK='disk4'

# Image name (no ext)
IMG='Piback20170826'

# Check for sensible disk
export PTYPE=$(diskutil list  /dev/$DSK | awk '/GUID_partition_scheme/ {print $2}; /Apple/ {print $2}; /Windows_NTFS/ {print $2}' )
if [ "$PTYPE" ]; then
    echo "Disk not a SD Card - Contains "$PTYPE
    exit
elif [ ! /dev/$DSK ]; then
    echo "/dev/$DSK not found"
    exit
fi

echo Ensure SD partitions are unmounted!
diskutil unmountDisk /dev/$DSK

# Check if image exists - else try to uncompress
if [ -s $IMG.img ]; then
    echo $IMG.img exists
elif [ -s $IMG.img.gz ]; then
    echo Copying $IMG.img.gz
    echo Ctl+T to show progress!
    #time  gunzip -k $IMG.img.gz
    time gunzip -kc $IMG.img.gz | sudo dd conv=sync of=/dev/r$DSK bs=4m
    exit
elif [ -s $IMG.zip ]; then
    echo Copying $IMG.zip
    echo Ctl+T to show progress!
    time unzip -p $IMG.zip | sudo dd conv=sync of=/dev/r$DSK bs=4m
    exit
fi

echo please wait - This takes some time
echo Ctl+T to show progress!
time sudo dd conv=sync if=$IMG.img of=/dev/r$DSK bs=4m

exit
```

PPS This is not strictly a Pi question - you should check `man dd` on your system.